# php random operator and their operations

Tags: php, random, operators

see my code below

```
$rand1 = rand(0,9);
$rand2 = rand(0,9);
$operator = array('*','/','+','-');
$randoperator = $operator[rand(0,3)];
$finaalvalue = $rand1."$randoperator".$rand2;

echo $rand1.$randoperator.$rand2.'='.$finaalvalue;
```

i want to take two random number and do random operation like +,-,*,/ and get their value

like 2-5=6

there is some problem while doing is what am i missing

Comment: What you are missing is, that you only concatenate the values which results in a string. You are not performing any operations on/with the values.

Comment: You could receive division by zero error. Keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is to use the [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function, but its use is highly discouraged:

> **Caution**   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is
>   discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other
>   option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass
>   any user provided data into it without properly validating it
>   beforehand.

The other option is to write separate blocks of code that perform the desired operation, then choose the appropriate branch, for example, by using a `switch...case` statement:

```
<?php
$rand1 = rand(0, 9);
$rand2 = rand(0, 9);
$operator = array('*', '/', '+', '-');
$randoperator = $operator[rand(0, 3)];
switch ($randoperator) {
    case "+":
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 + $rand2;
        break;
    case "-":
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 - $rand2;
        break;
    case "*":
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 * $rand2;
        break;
    case "/":
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 / $rand2;
        break;
}
echo $rand1 . $randoperator . $rand2 . '=' . $finaalvalue;
```

Comment: And what is if it's like: `5/0` ?

Comment: Divide overflow obviously.

Comment: @Rizier123 , Is it possible that OP creates a test to retrieve division by zero error with random appear?

Comment: @sectus I don't see one in OP's code! And in this solution neither.

Comment: @Rizier123 , I mean that you do not know the real problem of OP. So additional checking for this error could be an overenginiting. : )

Comment: @sectus But then i have to tell you that i expect from someone with such much reputation to think about this and point out to OP, that he has to check that!

Comment: @Rizier123 , you are right. And do not look at rep, and your reputation groth speed is higher than mine. :^ )

Comment: @Rizier123 higher reputation is not proportional to longer answers. If I must add additional points then I would rather begin my answer with: _what if I told you that `rand()` is not random enough_.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm reading your question right, you're computing a string, not applying the operator.  You must apply code to rand1 and rand2 to compute the final value.

The easy way is to eval $finaalvalue (`$finalvaalue = eval("return $finaalvalue ;");`) before echoing it.

If you need the code to run fast, or don't trust the input, use a switch or a function map:

```
$operatorMap = array(
    '+' => function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; },
    '*' => function($a, $b) { return $a * $b; },
    ...
);
$finaalvalue = $operatorMap[$operator]($rand1, $rand2);
```

PHP anonymous functions run slow compared to methods and normal functions, so avoid them in tight loops where speed matters.

Is this a homework question?  You should do your own work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Also if you do random calculation's you would have to check that there is no division by zero)

```
<?php

    function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
        $mathString = trim($mathString); 
        $mathString = str_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);    

        $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
        return 0 + $compute();
    }

    $rand1 = rand(0,9);
    $rand2 = rand(0,9);
    $operator = array('*','/','+','-');
    $randoperator = $operator[rand(0,3)];

    if($operator = "/" && $rand2 == 0)
        echo "Division by zero!";
    else {
        $finaalvalue = calculate_string($rand1 . $randoperator . $rand2);
        echo $rand1.$randoperator.$rand2.'='.$finaalvalue;
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to calculate mathematics operation by switch case. Your system can't perform mathematics operation, it will generate a string. That is concatenation.

```
$rand1 = rand(0,9);
$rand2 = rand(0,9);
$operator = array('*','/','+','-');
$randoperator = $operator[rand(0,3)];
switch($randoperator){
    case '+':
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 + $rand2;
        break;
    case '-':
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 - $rand2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if(!$rand2) $rand2++; 
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 / $rand2;
        break;
    case '*':
        $finaalvalue = $rand1 * $rand2;
        break;
}
echo $rand1.$randoperator.$rand2.'='.$finaalvalue;
```